# Verilog OR of array elements

Tags: arrays, for-loop, verilog, system-verilog

I want to OR a parameterized number of 32-bit buses as follows:
out_bus = bus1 | bus2 | bus 3 | ... | bus N;

I also want to declare the buses as an array (N is a fixed parameter, defined at compile time):

reg [31:0] bus[N-1:0];

The best I can figure how to do this is something like this:

```
parameter N;
reg [N-1:0] temp;
reg [31:0] out_bus;
reg [31:0] bus[N-1:0];

always @(*) begin       
   for (j=0; j<32; j=j+1) begin : bits
     for (k=0; k < N; k=k+1) begin : bus
       temp = bus[k][j];
     end
     out_bus[j] = |temp;
   end
end
```

This need to be synthesizable.  There's got to be a cleaner/better way, no?

Answer (score 5):

If you were using SystemVerilog, you could replace the entire `always` block with

```
assign out_bus = bus.or();
```

Comment: I am using System Verilog, so I don't think it can get better than this.

Answer (score 2):

This uses one fewer `for` loop and one fewer temporary signal:

```
reg [31:0] out_bus;
reg [31:0] bus[N-1:0];
integer k;

always @(*) begin       
    out_bus = {32{1'b0}};
    for (k=0; k < N; k=k+1) begin
        out_bus = out_bus | bus[k];
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code in quartus gave the expected results, as verified in schematic view.

```
module example #(
  parameter  WIDTH    = 32,
  parameter  DEPTH    = 4
)(
  input  [DEPTH-1:0][WIDTH-1:0]  DataIn,
  output reg [WIDTH-1:0]         DataOut
);

reg [WIDTH-1:0] ORDatain;

always@(*)
  begin
    ORDatain = 32'h0000_0000;
    for(int index=0; index <DEPTH; index++)
      ORDatain = ORDatain | DataIn[index];
  end

assign DataOut = ORDatain;

endmodule
```